# Why is random.randint() giving a ValueError?

Tags: python

I get the "ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()". How do I fix that?

This is my code:

```
# Bunnies and Badgers (github.com/Zwengel/PythonGame)
import pygame, random
width, height = int(pygame.display.Info().current_w), int(pygame.display.Info().current_h)
badheight1 = height/9.6
badheight2 = height/1.12
badheight = random.randint(badheight1, badheight2)
```

Comment: `How do I fix that?` use integers, as suggested by the error...

Comment: Isn't it already an integer?

Comment: @wb9688 are you on python3.x?

Comment: @wb9688: mostly you can answer that question, and anyway, the error tells you it is not.

Comment: @njzk2 Can i simply do `badheight = random.randint(int(badheight1), int(badheight2))`

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to acheive, not what you will do with that value, so all I can say is **possibly**. Or you can use a method that accept floats as boundaries, such as uniform. It all depends on what you are doing with that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python when you use `/` operator with an operand as float it returns a float , so `badheight1` and `badheight2` are float and you are trying to pass float into `random.randint()` causing the issue , if you want integers use `//` . Example -

```
badheight1 = height//9.6
badheight2 = height//1.12
badheight = random.randint(badheight1, badheight2)
```

Comment: the point on the version used is not relevant, since 9.6 is a float.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> randint(self, a, b) method of random.Random instance
>       Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.

Both endpoints must be integers, you are passing floats.

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(INT, INT)` is the correct way to call the function. Use integers instead of floats. I suggest this:

```
random.randint(10 ,1)
```